# Getting User Input Without JOptionPane (Java)

Tags: java

I have made a game in Java that allows you to create and play your own worlds. While creating your world there is a wall entity that you can place. This wall entity can slide, but in order to slide it needs the direction (horizontal/Vertical), distance, and speed. Currently I am using a few JOptionPane to get those values everytime you place one of those blocks. My question is how can I get those values from the user without using a JOptionPane? (If you need any code please let me know).

This is what I have:

```
private void placeWall() {
    int slidable = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Does This Block Slide?", "Slide", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

   if (slidable == 0) {
        String[] options = { "Horizontal", "Vertical"};
        int direction = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose Direction", "Direction", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, 0);

        int speed = getSpeed();
        int distance = getDistance();

        if (direction == 0)
              wallSlidables.add(new SlideHorizontal(speed, distance));
        else
              wallSlidables.add(new SlideVertical(speed, distance));
   }
}
```

Source Code: [GitHub](https://github.com/IssiahB/The-Traveler-Game)

Comment: Could you use the mouse pointer to place it? Are you using a canvas for this?

Comment: @kfrajer Yeah im using a canvas. And I can place the block already, but I need those values so I can save it to a file.

Comment: if you provide an mcve or some code, you might get more answers

Comment: @kfrajer what is a mcve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @kfrajer Thank You. But i decided to just make them all not slide for now.

Comment: You just need to provide some code to get your context. It is hard to suggest ideas or provide an answer without seeing your approach. You could use the p5.js library for instance.

Comment: @kfrajer Ok I provided some code in the question.

Comment: Correction to my prev comment... p5js isfor js. For java, use this reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html

Comment: You need to work with mouse pressed and mouseDragged events and then trigger calling the function above where you can access the mouse variables .

Comment: @kfrajer I have a function called update that gets called everytime the mouse is clicked and released. And is passed the x and y of the mouse. Then I use that method to call placeWall().